# Apache Spark Naive Bayes based Text Classification

Tags: apache-spark, text-mining

im trying to use Apache Spark for document classification.

For example i have two types of Class (C and J)

Train data is :

```
C, Chinese Beijing Chinese
C, Chinese Chinese Shanghai
C, Chinese Macao
J, Tokyo Japan Chinese
```

And test data is :
Chinese Chinese Chinese Tokyo Japan // What is ist J or C ?

How i can train and predict as above datas. I did Naive Bayes text classification with Apache Mahout, however no with Apache Spark.

How can i do this with Apache Spark?

Comment: Have you checked ML lib in spark? I think it has supported naive bayes already.

Comment: I've checked, however, i couldnt do it

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it doesn't look like there is any simple tool to do that in Spark yet. But you can do it manually by first creating a dictionary of terms. Then compute IDFs for each term and then convert each documents into vectors using the TF-IDF scores.

There is a post on http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/classifiying-documents-using-naive-bayes-on-apache-spark-mllib/ that explains how to do it (with some code as well).

Comment: Thanks, i did it in my way. http://kodcu.com/2014/06/apache-spark-ile-naive-bayes-siniflandirma/

Answer (score 3):

Spark can do this in very simple way. The key step is: 1 use HashingTF to get the item frequency. 2 convert the data to the form of the bayes model needed.

```
def testBayesClassifier(hiveCnt:SQLContext){
    val trainData = hiveCnt.createDataFrame(Seq((0,"aa bb aa cc"),(1,"aa dd ee"))).toDF("category","text")
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")
    val wordsData = tokenizer.transform(trainData)
    val hashTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("features").setNumFeatures(20)
    val featureData = hashTF.transform(wordsData) //key step 1
    val trainDataRdd = featureData.select("category","features").map {
    case Row(label: Int, features: Vector) =>  //key step 2
    LabeledPoint(label.toDouble, Vectors.dense(features.toArray))
    }
    //train the model
    val model = NaiveBayes.train(trainDataRdd, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")

    //same for the test data
    val testData = hiveCnt.createDataFrame(Seq((-1,"aa bb"),(-1,"cc ee ff"))).toDF("category","text")
    val testWordData = tokenizer.transform(testData)
    val testFeatureData = hashTF.transform(testWordData)
    val testDataRdd = testFeatureData.select("category","features").map {
    case Row(label: Int, features: Vector) =>
    LabeledPoint(label.toDouble, Vectors.dense(features.toArray))
    }
    val testpredictionAndLabel = testDataRdd.map(p => (model.predict(p.features), p.label))
```

}

Comment: Excellent...Above code help us a lot!!! I have one query in the above code. What is the use of the label in the test set?

Comment: If you have the right labels, you can use them to get the accurate rate of the classify result. If you have not the  right labels, you can put any number here.  The model need the input data in this format.

Comment: Thanks for the very good example. After running the test , I can compare the label and the predicted value.                                                                      If I want to verify the predicted value against the "text" in the test data , I would need the "text" column also in the test. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Can we avoid create labelled point of test data . For Example I can build the Vectors.dense(features.toArray) directly and use it for prediction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mlib's naive bayes classifier for this. A sample example is given in the link.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html

Comment: What is the comment // training set ? How does it calculated? Only comment. How can i convert my text data to sparse format for training and test data ??

Answer (score 1):

There any many classification methods (logistic regression, SVMs, neural networks,LDA, QDA...), you can either implement yours or use MLlib classification methods (actually, there are logistic regression and SVM implemented in MLlib)

What you need to do is transform your features to a vector, and labels to doubles.

For examples, your dataset will look like:

```
1, (2,1,0,0,0,0)
1, (2,0,1,0,0,0)
0, (1,0,0,1,0,0)
0, (1,0,0,0,1,1)
```

And tour test vector:

```
(3,0,0,0,1,1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did with Naive Bayes with Spark, how can do this app with SVM ? https://github.com/rahmanusta/Spark-Bayes

Comment: You can use the Spark MLlib library http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html

Comment: How can i convert my data to svm format in Spark? I know Spark supports it.

Comment: Checkout example here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/SparseNaiveBayes.scala