# Apache Spark: Detect buying intent in a sentence

Tags: java, apache-spark, nlp

I have an Apache Spark application, written in scala, which does some basic processing of the input data received. Input data are sentences from a text file. I need to classify the ones with **Buying** intention. For example, if the sentence goes like : "*Where can I buy a blue shoe?*", then this counts as one.

What classifier/ ML program can I use to build this? A scala/java tool would be suitable. I am new to NLP/ML.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is essentially a **Binary Classification** problem. Therefore you need to:

1. Prepare labeled data as the training dataset: each sentence is labeled as 1 if it has buying intent and 0 if it hasn't.
2. Feature transformation: You need to transfer natural language sentences to numeric features. Please refer to the [TF-IDF](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf) method.

As for binary classifiers, you actually have multiple choices, e.g., Naive Bayes, SVM, Decision Trees, etc. Please check [Spark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-classification-regression.html) for its supported classifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this thread: [Apache Spark Naive Bayes based Text Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011418/apache-spark-naive-bayes-based-text-classification)

However, the thread is almost 1 year old. Now there seams to be a litte more support in Spark, see [Term Frequency](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html), [Tokenizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer) and [Stop Words Remover](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover)